# VSCode: normal word completion

Tags: visual-studio-code

I understand that VSCode has intelisense. But sometimes one only needs a simple completion of a variable name that has appeared somewhere in the same file or in the already opened files. Like what Vim has for `Ctrl+o Ctrl+p`. Is it possible to do it in VSCode?

Comment: What's `Ctrl+o Ctrl+p`? Did you mean `Ctrl+n` and `Ctrl+p`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Edit: from vscode **1.51** it should be possible:

```js
"editor.wordBasedSuggestionsMode": "currentDocument" | "matchingDocuments" | "allDocuments"
```

---

It is possible now with the extension: [All Autocomplete](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Atishay-Jain.All-Autocomplete).

It auto-completes based on words in all opened files.

---

Related issue https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/5312

Comment: This extension has many bugs. The author has not repaired anything for a long time. At the moment it doesn't work (for PHP) due to https://github.com/atishay/vscode-allautocomplete/issues/51.

Comment: Work has been done on that issue to get word completion based on all open files of the same language, see https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/5312#issuecomment-724717894

Answer (score 1):

It has been years, I believe now VSCode (1.52.1) has supported Ctrl+p / Ctrl+n for word autocompletion if you have Vim extenstion installed and enabled.

However, it still requires Ctrl+space to trigger the autocompltion popup then you can use Ctrl+p / Ctrl+n to go next or prev

If you dislike to press Ctrl+space, I found adding following in the `keybindings.json` could help and behave the same as Vim.

```
    {
        "key": "ctrl+p",
        "command": "editor.action.triggerSuggest",
        "when": "editorHasCompletionItemProvider && !suggestWidgetVisible && textInputFocus && !editorReadonly"
    },
    {
        "key": "ctrl+n",
        "command": "editor.action.triggerSuggest",
        "when": "editorHasCompletionItemProvider && !suggestWidgetVisible && textInputFocus && !editorReadonly"
    },
```

Hope you like this.